# Myth 2 on 64 bit Xubuntu 13.10 needing libs openal 32 bit, and how to install that?

Tags: libraries

I Have Myth 2 Soulblighter with no in game sound at all. Which needs lib-openal 32 bit for it to actually work. I'm of course running Xubuntu 13.10 64 bit, any one know how to get this installed for 32 bit games that need it?

Answer (score 0):

You can install a 32-bit version like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenal1:i386
```